# Logcat Broken. No output in eclipse or terminal

Tags: android, mobile, logcat

My logcat output has completely disappeared from both eclipse and "adm logcat".  In both instances they're just blank.

I've tried:

```
   adb kill-server / adb start-server

   Restarted eclipse 

   Rebooted computer (dell mini 10v)

   Rebooted phone (cliqxt)

   Unplugged and replugged in phone usb connection
```

I can't really test with the emulator because it takes a minimum of 45 minutes to start it on this machine. 
Anyone have any idea what can cause this?

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the hint of killing adb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. It was an issue with the phone. I removed the battery and SIM and then logcat puked out 6 hours of logs on reboot. The phone was storing them and not flushing them out for some reason.